# Using csv.DictWriter to output an in-memory gzipped csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, io, gzip

I want to use a `DictWriter` from Python's `csv` module to generate a .csv file that's compressed using GZip. I need to do this all in-memory, so utilizing local files is out of the question.

However, I'm having trouble dealing with each module's type requirements in Python 3. Assuming that I got the general structure correctly, I can't make both modules work together because `DictWriter` needs to write to a `io.StringIO` buffer, while `GZip` needs a `io.BytesIO` object.

So, when I try to do:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
compressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode='wb')
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(buffer, ["a", "b"], extrasaction="ignore")
```

I get:

`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

And trying to use `io.StringIO` with `GZip` doesn't work either. How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you **have** to use the csv module? Could you just *manually* create a comma separated bytes object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A roundabout way would be to write it to a `io.StringIO` object first and then convert the content back to `io.BytesIO`:

```
s = io.StringIO()
b = io.BytesIO()

dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(s, ["a", "b"], extrasaction="ignore")

... # complete your write operations ...

s.seek(0)  # reset cursor to the beginning of the StringIO stream
b.write(s.read().encode('utf-8')) # or an encoding of your choice

compressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=b, mode='wb')

... 

s.close()   # Remember to close your streams!
b.close()
```

Though as @wwii's comment suggest, depending on the size of your data, perhaps it's more worthwhile to write your own `csv` in `bytes` instead.

Comment: Ended up going with this one, since it's more simple. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution requires twice the buffer space than a wrapper does.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `io.TextIOWrapper` to seamlessly transform a text stream into a binary one:

```
import io
import gzip
import csv
buffer = io.BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode='wb') as compressed:
    with io.TextIOWrapper(compressed, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(wrapper, ["a", "b"], extrasaction="ignore")
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 3}])
print(buffer.getvalue()) # dump the compressed binary data
buffer.seek(0)
dict_reader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode='rb'), encoding='utf-8'))
print(list(dict_reader)) # see if uncompressing the compressed data gets us back what we wrote
```

This outputs:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x9c6[\\\x02\xffJ\xd4I\xe2\xe5\xe52\xd41\x02\x92&:\xc6@\x12\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x03\x00\x85k\xa2\x9e\x12\x00\x00\x00'
[OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]), OrderedDict([('a', '4'), ('b', '3')])]
```

Comment: This is the better solution since it allows streaming of huge files without blowing up in memory.